# Fluent NHibernate Mapping XDocument property to Oracle XMLType

Tags: nhibernate, oracle9i, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, xmltype

I am looking for the best way to map from an XDocument property type to an Oracle XMLType? I am mapping to a legacy database and have no control over the schema. It is Oracle 9i.

I have read that version 3 of nHibernate provides out the box functionality for this type of mapping. I am using version 3.1 with fluent mappings and I receive the following error when using the default map on a create:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.set_DbType(DbType value)
>   at NHibernate.Driver.DriverBase.SetCommandParameters(IDbCommand cmd, SqlType[] sqlTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Driver\DriverBase.cs: line 180
>   at NHibernate.Driver.DriverBase.GenerateCommand(CommandType type, SqlString sqlString, SqlType[] parameterTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Driver\DriverBase.cs: line 136
>   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.Generate(CommandType type, SqlString sqlString, SqlType[] parameterTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs: line 78
>   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.PrepareBatchCommand(CommandType type, SqlString sql, SqlType[] parameterTypes) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs: line 146
>   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs: line 2616
>   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs: line 3050
>   at NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityInsertAction.cs: line 59
>   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line 136
>   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line 125
>   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs: line 170
>   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs: line 241
>   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultFlushEventListener.cs: line 20
>   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs: line 1470

I got round this my writing my own user type which converts between an XDocument and a string:

```
public SqlType[] SqlTypes
{
get { return (new SqlType[] { new StringClobSqlType() }); }
}

public Type ReturnedType
{
get { return (typeof(XDocument)); }
}

public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
{
XDocument xDoc = null;

int columnIndex = rs.GetOrdinal(names[0]);
if (!rs.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
{
xDoc = XDocument.Parse((rs[columnIndex].ToString()));
}

return (xDoc);
}

public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
{
IDbDataParameter parameter = (IDbDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];

if (value == null)
{
parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
XDocument xDoc = (XDocument)value;
parameter.Value = xDoc.ConvertToString();

}
}
```

This worked fine until the string was greater than 4000 characters in length. Now I get the error:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not insert: [XmlBlob#95586][SQL: INSERT INTO XMLBLOB (CAT_CODE, BLB_BLOB, BLB_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
>   ----> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only update I needed to be able to save more than 4000 characters to the XMLType column was to set the parameter type as OracleDbType.XmlType in the set method for my user type implementation:

```
    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        IDbDataParameter parameter = (IDbDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index];
       ((OracleParameter)parameter).OracleDbTypeEx = OracleDbType.XmlType;

        if (value == null)
        {
            parameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            XDocument xDoc = (XDocument)value;
            parameter.Value = xDoc.ConvertToString();
        }
    }
```